# Subsetting R with "IN" like operator

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset using a vector of characters. I'd like to pull back all rows whose corresponding X column are in this vector. My experimenting is bringing back zilch and so is my search.

```
list<-c("1","2","3")
sub<-subset(data,x==list,1:4)
```

That and syntax pretty close to it won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show some example data and a desired result

Comment: there is a `%in%` operator, `x %in% list`

Comment: I am McNulty and you are truly Bunk - you helped me bigtime!

Comment: @MarkRomano hahaha! that's fantastic xD

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @bunk you could use the `%in%` operator:

```
DF <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),val=c(4,5,6))
val.list <- c(5,6)
subDF <- subset(DF, val %in% val.list)
subDF
  id val
2  2   5
3  3   6
```